# how to make an operation with php and two csv files using same ID

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm new to php and I'm looking to do something with two different csv files with php.

here are screenshots of my two csv files : 
https://www.noelshack.com/2019-25-4-1561015547-csv1.png
https://www.noelshack.com/2019-25-4-1561015547-csv2.png

In my two csv I have similar ID and different prices ("Prix HT" column).

What I want to do is check similar ID, and do an operation with the price.

For example in CSV1 for the ID 96885 I have the price of 40.
in CSV2 for the same ID I have two prices : 45 and 48.

What I want in php is a way to create another column that calculate the difference of the price of the csv2 file according to the csv1 file. 
In example above the code should result 5 and 8.

I'm planning to do such a thing on massive CSV files.

I only figure how to make the csv files appear in an array with php using the fgetcsv function but I don't know how to do next.

here is the code I have so far, not so much because I don't know how to do next :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

set_time_limit (0);
$testcsv = fopen('test.csv', 'a+');
$testcsv2 = fopen("test2.csv", "a+");
$fichierFinal = fopen('final.csv', 'w');

while($row=fgetcsv($testcsv, 99999,';')){
    $ID_product = $row[0];
    $price_product = $row[3];

    while($row1=fgetcsv($testcsv2, 99999,';')){
        $ID_combination = $row1[0];
        $price_combination = intval($row1[3]);



        if($ID_product == $ID_combination ){
            $fprice = $price_combination - $price_product;
            $row1[3]=$fprice;

        }
        fputcsv($fichierFinal, $row1, ";");
    };

}
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have so far and it will be easier to show you how to modify it to do the job you want.

Comment: @NigelRen I have edited my original post with the code I have for now

Comment: @NigelRen I have edited my code with something I tried, but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the script. Pay attention, I use two CSV files with just one column each:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

set_time_limit (0);
$row1= array();
$row =array();
$rowFinal = array();
$testcsv = fopen('file1.csv', 'a+');
$fichierFinal = fopen('totale.csv', 'w');

while($row=fgetcsv($testcsv, 99999,';')){
    $ID_product = intval($row[0]);

    $testcsv2 = fopen('file2.csv', 'a+');
    while($row1=fgetcsv($testcsv2, 99999,';')){
        $ID_combination = intval($row1[0]);
        if($ID_product == $ID_combination ){


            $fprice = $ID_product + $ID_combination;
            //echo $fprice;
            $rowFinal[]= $fprice;
            echo $fprice . "  "; 
        }

    }
    fclose($testcsv2);

}

fputcsv($fichierFinal, $rowFinal, ";");

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know.

Comment: thanks but apparently there something's wrong, the final csv file is empty, and when I var_dump the rowFinal var it result :
array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }

Comment: I have updated the response with a tested script. Let me know